# Understanding /camera/depth/points

Tags: ros, kinect, camera-depth-points, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does the value in the 'data' field of the data published by /camera/depth/points represent? They are supposed to represent the distance of every pixel from the Kinect center point? How to I convert the data generated as point cloud into corresponding cartesian 3D coordinates ? An array of size [4915200x1] is generated. Which means distance to each pixel is represented using 16 entries in matrix (because 480 x 640 x 16 = 4915200).  How do I understand this. Please explain the program behind visualization of this pointcloud data in rviz .

I kept my kinect in front of an plain 2D wall parallel with it. I thought that I will get a matrix with uniform value through out as the wall is equidistant from kinect. But I get a data which I could not understand and decode!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201972/understanding-/camera/depth/points/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The data is all the point clouds data fields (x, y, z) encoded into that array. Usually you don't read that by hand. Use a [PCL Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#ROS_C.2B-.2B-_interface) that allows you to directly get point data with x,y,z coordinates.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-29**:
Thanks a lot for your reply. I will go thro it.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-03-26**:
i have converted pointcloud2 from kinect to pointcloudxyz. Are x,y,z coordinates in meters or mm?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-26**:
m                     ,

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-07**:
for the camera/depth/points topic. does it publish coordinates of pixel or world coordinate. Im a bit confused

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-04-08**:
These are x,y,z points in the frame that is passed in the message header.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-08**:
my frame id is camera_depth_optical_frame. are the xyz in my frame world coordinates? which will give depth from kinect to objects?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-04-08**:
They are very likely relative to the kinect sensor.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-08**:
i still dont get what you mean